# Celery with beanstalkd broker throws exception

Tags: python, celery, message-queue, beanstalkd

I am trying to configure beanstalkd as the broker for celery. I am using this [reference](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/beanstalk.html).

Here is my code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('test_celery',
    broker='beanstalk://localhost:11300',
            include=['tasks'])

celery.conf.update(
  CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

I get the following error when I run the worker. This happens without even calling any tasks. I have not specifed any beanstalkd tube anywhere.

```
[2013-10-30 13:36:49,189: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost.   
Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 410, in start
self.consume_messages()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 904, in    
consume_messages
self.connection.drain_events(timeout=10.0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 281, in drain_events
return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 763,   
in drain_events
item, channel = get(timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/scheduling.py", line 39, 
in get
return self.fun(resource, **kwargs), resource
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 783, 
in _drain_channel
return channel.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 580,   
in drain_events
return self._get_many(self._active_queues, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/beanstalk.py", line 75, in 
_get_many
if active not in watching]
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/beanstalkc.py", line 195, in watch
return int(self._interact_value('watch %s\r\n' % name, ['WATCHING']))
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/beanstalkc.py", line 107, in _interact_value
return self._interact(command, expected_ok, expected_err)[0]
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/beanstalkc.py", line 90, in _interact
raise UnexpectedResponse(command.split()[0], status, results)

UnexpectedResponse: (u'watch', 'BAD_FORMAT', [])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have read about `celery` but I haven't worked on it. There is `celeryd` daemon. Try starting it first. `ps -ef | grep celeryd` to check if the daemon is running. I guess that't the issue.

Comment: I tried by changing the broker to `mongodb` and it worked. There is no need to run `celeryd`.

Comment: @HussainTamboli If you see at the TB, you will note that the connection is successful, but some mis-match in data formatting is causing this